# mysql: on update cascade, on delete set null not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies ( 
    title varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    year YEAR NOT NULL, 
    length int NOT NULL,  
    genre ENUM('action', 'adventure', 'comedy', 'family', 'crime', 'drama', 'fantasy', 'historical') NOT NULL, 
    studioName varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    producerCNum int REFERENCES MoviesExec(certNum)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (title, year) 
);

CREATE TABLE MoviesExec ( 
    name varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
    address varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    certNum int NOT NULL,   
    netWorth int NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (certNum) 
);
```

To test the "ON DELETE" and "ON UPDATE" statements, I inserted one row each into Movies and one row into MoviesExec. Into Movies, I inserted:

```
INSERT INTO Movies
VALUES('star wars', 1977, 142, 'action', 'lucasfilm', 12345);
```

Into MoviesExec, I inserted:

```
INSERT INTO MoviesExec
VALUES('george lucas', '100 beverly hills', 12345, 1000000);
```

Then, I tried updating the certNum of MoviesExec, which should have lead to a change in the producerCNum of Movies:

```
UPDATE MoviesExec SET certNum = 1234567 where name = 'george lucas';
```

The update shows up in MoviesExec with certNum now being equal to 1234567, but when I do

```
SELECT * FROM Movies
```

The producerCNum is still equal to 12345. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT create a foreign key reference.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movies ( 
    title varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    year YEAR NOT NULL, 
    length int NOT NULL,  
    genre ENUM('action', 'adventure', 'comedy', 'family', 'crime', 'drama', 'fantasy', 'historical') NOT NULL, 
    studioName varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    producerCNum int,
    FOREIGN KEY MoviesExec_certNum (producerCNum) REFERENCES MoviesExec (certNum)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (title, year) 
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=88c73339ab9331450c95cf81445b46d7)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. In the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) it says:

"MySQL parses but ignores “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification"

So what I was doing before was an inline REFERENCES specification. I had to specify the REFERENCES clauses within a FOREIGN KEY specification, which I did below:

```
ALTER TABLE Movies
ADD CONSTRAINT producer_fk
FOREIGN KEY (producerCNum) REFERENCES MoviesExec(certNum) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Movies
ADD CONSTRAINT producer_fk2
FOREIGN KEY (producerCNum) REFERENCES MoviesExec(certNum) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```